# xcode 4, c++, highlight warning "unused parameter"

Tags: xcode4

I have next problem( using xcode4, language c++, compiler LLVM GCC 4.2 )

In the source code, do not highlights warnings "unused parameter". In the project settings, this warning has flag 'Yes'.

For example:

```
void foo( int x, int y ) // There are no highlighting of warning
{
    return x*x;
}
```

What should I do to switch on a highlighting?

Answer (score 0):

You'll find the compiler settings in the project settings under Build Settings.

http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2009-11-07/warnings

Comment: In the Build Settings, paragraph LLVM GCC 4.2 Warnings - warning **Unused Parameers** has flag **Yes**.

Comment: Ensure the file extension is .mm not .m

Comment: Language is c++, so file extension is .cpp (and i can't change it to .mm)

Comment: Hmm... Not sure, try upgrade to 4.3.x?